# How to get Get Code from https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize

Tags: android, fitbit

I'm referring https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/oauthinteractivetutorial link for getting access token in Android App.

**Step 1:**

Here I have hard coded registered app details.

```
 String urls = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?" +
                            "response_type=code" +
                            "&client_id=228K7X" +
                            "&expires_in=2592000" +
                            "&scope=profile%20settings%20weight" +
                            "&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com/" ;
```

From this link I should get Code.If I copy Past this in browser I'm getting code like this

http://www.google.com/?**code=e800eef2374bd6c1f5cc5e8dab65d4d4bff60406#*=***

---

I've tried like below in android code ,But not getting expected result.Can any one help me for this?

```
                      URL url = new URL(urls);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get back exactly? A JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Fixed.Find answer below,I'm using Webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String urls = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?" +
                "response_type=code" +
                "&client_id=228K7X" +
                "&expires_in=2592000" +
                "&scope=profile%20settings%20weight" +
                "&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com/" ;

        Log.i(TAG," urls ? "+urls);

        webView.loadUrl(urls);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                Log.i(TAG," onPageFinished ? "+url);
            }

        });
```